# Chrome Plugin: pop-up alert when some web elements changed after refreshing

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

There are some available plugins already for chrome that can act as an auto page refresher. However if I want to check if some specific elements in the website have changed or not (e.g. an element inside a table) after refreshing, is there any available plugin that can act like that (or Firefox plugin)? Or is there any way to learn how to develop such plugin? Thanks a lot.

p.s. no experience developing chrome plugin, little bit knowledge in C++ and Java

Comment: Nice addon idea. You can make this pretty easily. Im not sure how to on chrome but if you need help i can help you make a firefox version.

Comment: Never mind, I eventually find some page monitor plugins that do the similar jobs. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Take a look at Distill Web Monitor extension for Chrome/Firefox. It performs the checks in background and displays a notification on change.